# Why is direct output to network share much slower than inter-buffering?

Tags: networking, fuse, buffering

This is an Arch Linux System where I mounted a network device over SSHFS (SFTP) using GVFS managed by Nemo FM. I'm using Handbrake to convert a video that lies on my SSD.

Observations:

- If I encode the video using Handbrake and set the destination to a folder on the SSD, I get 100 FPS
- If I copy a file from the SSD to the network share (without Handbrake), I get 3 MB/s
- However, if I combine both (using Handbrake with the destination set to a folder on the network share), I get 15 FPS and 0.2 MB/s, both being significantly lower than the available capacities.

I suppose this is a buffering problem. But where does it reside? Is it Handbrake's fault, or perhaps GVFS caching not enough? Long story short, **how can the available capacities be fully used in this situation?**

Answer (score 1):

When accessing the file over SFTP Handbrake will be requesting small portions of the file rather than the entire thing, meaning it is starting and finishing lots of transfers and adding that much more overhead.

Your best best for solving this issue is to transfer the ENTIRE file to the SSD before performing the encoding. 3 MB/s is slower than direct access to an older, large capacity mechanical drive and as such will not give you the performance you are looking for so direct access to a network share is not recommended unless you can speed up those transfers significantly.

Comment: +1 for your explanation.However you misunderstood one thing: I'm not reading from the network, but I'm writing to it (the *destination* is on the network, not the source (which effectively is on the SSD)). This means that introducing proper buffering somehow might actually solve the problem without creating the need to copy the entire file afterwards. Therefore I'm still thriving for a buffer-driven method.